# Problema con pyttsx

Tags: python, terminal

Estoy intentando trabajar con el modulo pyttsx .Leí la documentación y seguí todo al pie de la letra. Sin embargo cuando intento correr un script tan simple como este:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Sally sells seashells by the seashore.')
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Lanza un error que es el siguiente :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'

Instale el modulo en un entorno virtual. Por lo que me dirigí hacia la carpeta donde se encuentra alojado en codigo del modulo. Alli tiene su script **init** en el se importa el modulo engine de la siguiente manera

> from engine import Engine

Esta importando la clase Engine que se encuentra alojada en engine. Sin embargo no me deja correr el script porque no encuentra este modulo. Ya revise e incluso estan al mismo nivel. Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo lo has intalado?, ¿qué versión de Python estás usando?

Comment: Hola, Lo he instalado en un entorno virtual. Debido a que asi indica su documentacion, Especificamente en virtualenv . y uso la version 3.6.1 de python... @César

Answer (score 3):

El módulo [pyttsx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx/1.1) está poco mantenido por lo que parece, la última versión en pypi es la 1.1 del 2012 (aunque parece que hay una versión más reciente según la documentación, la 1.2 del 2015) y está escrito en Python 2.

Posiblemente arreglando los import en el código fuente se pueda hacer funcionar. También puedes usar Python 2, pero es preferible ir portando todo el código de Python 2 a Python 3 dada la más que próxima muerte de la rama 2 (si nada cambia para la PyCon de 2020 se dejará de dar soporte a Python 2). De todas formas no deja de estar bastante desactualizado el módulo.

Existe un fork reciente y mantenido para Python 3 / Python 2 que es el que debes considerar usar llamado **pyttsx3:**

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx3/2.6

Su manejo se supone que es idéntico a pyttsx (aunque nunca he usado este último). He usado pyttsx3 anteriormente y funciona perfectamente en Python 3.6 y 3.5 que es donde lo he probado. Tu código no cambia nada, solo el nombre del módulo:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Sally sells seashells by the seashore.')
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Exactamente ese es mi problema. debido a que es un proyecto medianamente largo ya tengo mucho codigo que funciona en py3 . Sin embargo utilizare esa opcion de pyttsx3 a ver si funciona. gracias

Comment: @limg21 como comento funciona perfectamente en Python 3.6, aunque lo he usado muy poco y solo para proyectos lúdico y personales. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Mirando un poco el código parece que `pyttsx` solo funciona para las versiones de Python 2, si no tienes problemas en usar esa versión de Python te sugiero que crees tu entorno virtual usando esa versión:

```
$ virtualenv --python=`which python2` venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/cesar/venv/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/cesar/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install pyttsx
Collecting pyttsx
Installing collected packages: pyttsx
Successfully installed pyttsx-1.1
(venv) $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyttsx
>>>
```

Ejecuta sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. sim embargo no creo que esta opcion me funcione. debido a que es un proyecto extenso y que tiene muchas librerias ya compatibles con python 3. Por lo tanto buscare otras opciones

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install python-espeak

eso es todo lo que te falta... me paso lo mismo

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad. Podrias tratar de expandirla un poco mas? mira [answer]